# Finding $\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{1}{a + i \cdot b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for an expression in terms of $a$, $b$ and $N$ for the following series:

$\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{1}{a + i \cdot b} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{a + 2\cdot b} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a + N \cdot b}$

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There's is no closed formula for this sum. It can be rewritten as integrals or special functions, but usually those are not considered closed formulas.

Comment: Hi @jjagmath Thanks for your answer. Would you mind expanding on "It can be rewritten as integrals or special functions". Thanks

Comment: Of course, but in this forum you're expected to share your own work and thoughts on the problem. Please, edit your question to include your efforts. May be if you work a little on the sum you can you see why is enough to consider the case $b=1$?

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid having this question closed, please include a description of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no closed form for that expression, but you can have a nice notion of how big is that sum. First, you must know that

$$H_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i = \ln (n) + \gamma_n$$

such that $\gamma_n \to \gamma \approx 0.577$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{a+i} = H_{a+n} - H_{a} = \ln (1 + \frac na) + \gamma'_n$$

what you want is $$\frac1b\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{\frac ab+i} = \frac1b \ln(1+\frac {nb}{a}) + \gamma''_n$$

so this is a good guess for the value of that sum for large $n$:

$$\frac1b \ln (1+\frac {bn}a)$$

$$\gamma''_n \to 0$$ as $n$ grows

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hellofriends